# Custom dialog too small

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, customdialog

I have an android activity that implements a custom dialog.The application is running ok but the dialog is too small,i want to display a bigger dialog.How can i achieve this?
Here is my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

         <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="@drawable/view_more_borders">

         <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:gravity="center_vertical">

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/share_amount"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Company Name:"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                 android:textColor="@color/nice_blue"
                 android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCompanyName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.80"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

         </LinearLayout>


         <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:gravity="center_vertical">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Price per share:"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/nice_blue" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewprice_pershare"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Yesterday"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Yesterday"
                android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/company"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:gravity="center_vertical">

              <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:text="Total cost:"

                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                  android:textColor="@color/nice_blue" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_totalcost"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Yesterday"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Yesterday"
                android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/company"
                android:text=" "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
         </LinearLayout>


         <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:gravity="center_vertical">

                 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:text="Number of shares:"

                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textColor="@color/nice_blue" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/shareNumber"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                 >

            <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:gravity="center_vertical">


              <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Payment method:"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/nice_blue" />

             <Spinner
                 android:id="@+id/spinner_paymentmode"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="2" />

         </LinearLayout>   
     </LinearLayout>
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_buy_shares"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
    android:text="Buy" />
```

And here is my output.I want to increase the width and height of the dialog.
[image]

And my java file

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public MyDialogFragment() {

}

private EditText mEditText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment, container);
    // mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
    // getDialog().setTitle("Hello");
    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Post your java file. you have to set width and height of your dialog in java file.

Comment: @Andrain i have posted it.

Comment: @mungaihkamau did you resolved your problem?

Comment: @JaAd no,am still trying to figure out something from google

Comment: @mungaihkamau try again my piece of code.

Comment: Add RelativeLayout as the root element for your custom dialog layout, It worked for me!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Change your dialog dimension on runtime:

```
yourDialog.show();
yourDialog.getWindow().setLayout((6 * width)/7, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

You can do that for both dimension, in my example i only changed the width.
Hope it helps!

EDIT

I forgot to mention where i took width:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

EDIT 2

Try this code:

```
Dialog yourDialog = dialogFragment.getDialog();
yourDialog.getWindow().setLayout((6 * width)/7, (4 * height)/5);
```

Comment: how have you you initialised width?

Comment: @Chris the code simply "tells" to the dialog to take 6/7 of your screen width and 4/5 of your screehn height.

Comment: but if im am giving match parent as width, still the issue why?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria sorry, I didn't noticed your comment. I don't know, but maybe it is not allowed anymore to have a dialog with this parameter. I think that even if this is useful, having a big dialog is not a good solution (design). Even if my solution is working, maybe it is not perfect anymore. If you should show a lot of info, then re-think it and use a Fragment or an Activity.

Comment: This is it. Thank you! Was using `getActivity().getWindow()` instead of `getDialog().getWindow()` and note this must be called in `onStart()` when the ui is ready and not in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Just an additional information, if you want the height to wrap content, you can use `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(yourWidth, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)` .

Answer (score 20):

Setting android:minWidth and android:minHeight in the custom layout does the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

put below line in onCreate

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
```

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27236008/1429832)

Comment: Yes, it works, but 1) dialog expands to whole width, 2) this theme is deprecated, you may use `Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth`, `Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth` or any material. Also setting `style` or `android:theme` in layout doesn't solve, so we should use this method `setStyle()`.

Answer (score 6):

Dialogs are sized by their content. You can add padding and margins on the outer layout to consume more space, but that will not redistribute the views inside.

Comment: This is the best explanation! In your custom layout you can't use match parent, because it's always wrap_content used by Dialog itself

Answer (score 6):

```
<style name="full_screen_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth" type="dimen">600dp</item>
</style>
```

Use this in `style.xml` file and use this style in dialog class

Comment: the only thing that works for me here is the minWidth=600dp. In my case I didn't need the other style elements

Answer (score 3):

Add **android:minWidth** / **android:minHeight** to your root view. See example below:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="300dp"
android:minHeight="500dp">
```

Answer (score 2):

The right solution is to override the `onCreateDialog` method rather than `onCreateView`, and create your dialog with a `AlertDialog.Builder`, as explained in the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#AlertDialog

Comment: If DialogFragment doesn't use `AlertDialog.Builder`, it won't help.

Answer (score 1):

The trick worked for me

```
  override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val metrics: DisplayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
        val width: Int = metrics.widthPixels
        dialog?.window?.setLayout(width - 58, 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For **setting dialog width and height as per device screen size**

```
    Display display;
    int DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight, DialogWidth, DialogHeight;
    Dialog dialog;

display =((WindowManager)activity_context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayWidth = display.getWidth();
        DisplayHeight = display.getHeight();

        if(DisplayHeight > DisplayWidth)
        {
            DialogWidth = (6 * DisplayWidth) / 7 ;
            DialogHeight = (4 * DisplayHeight) / 5 ;
        }
        else
        {
            DialogWidth = (6 * DisplayWidth) / 9 ;
            DialogHeight = (4 * DisplayHeight) / 5 ;
        }

        dialog = new Dialog(activity_context);

          // Set your dialog width and height dynamically as per your screen.

        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(DialogWidth,DialogHeight);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: would you be willing to assist me edit my code as per your solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to set `android:layout_height` to some value for base `LinearLayout`

for example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

<!-- right here -->
    android:layout_height="100dp"

android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I configured my project so that the default dialog theme for `DialogFragments` has a minimum width.

set the app's theme to your custom theme in the `AndroidManifest.xml`....alternatively, set the theme of the `Activity` hosting the `DialogFragment` to your app's custom theme.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld">

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">     <!-- set the app's theme to your custom theme -->

        .....

    </application>

</manifest>
```

define your custom theme in `values/styles.xml`, and override the default theme used for dialog fragments with one you define yourself.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

        <!-- override the default theme for DialogFragments -->
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>

    </style>

    <!--
        configure your custom theme for DialogFragments...
        use a theme that has MinWidth, so that the dialog is not "too small"
    -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth">

        <!-- override the default theme for DialogFragments spawned by this DialogFragment -->
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>

        <!--
            OPTIONAL: override the background for the dialog...i am using a dark theme,
            and for some reason, there is no themes for dialogs with dark backgrounds,
            so, i made my own.
        -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog__window_background</item>

        <!--
            add the title to the dialog's theme. you can remove it later by using
            DialogFragment.setStyle()
        -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">?android:windowNoTitle</item>

    </style>

    .....

</resources>
```

if you use a dark theme, and overrode `android:windowBackground` like i did in `AppTheme.Dialog`, then add a `drawable/dialog__window_background.xml` file with the contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="16dp"
    android:insetTop="16dp"
    android:insetRight="16dp"
    android:insetBottom="16dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="?dialogCornerRadius" />
        <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```