# Custom Dialog Layout Issue

Tags: android, dialog, android-relativelayout

I have implemented a Custom Dialog with Relative layout as Parent.. The issue is that the layout height goes match_parent size even i use wrap_content on Relative Layout...................................................................................................................................

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutPopup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Standered Delvery"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_count_popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6 Items"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/bg_ash"
        >
    </View>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_dismiss_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="DISMISS"
    android:textColor="@color/orange"
    />
```

This is the java code

```
totalCountTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            customDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_item_details_delvery_options);
            customDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ListView listView=(ListView)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.listview_popup) ;

            TextView count=(TextView)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.item_count_popup);
            count.setText(String.valueOf(arrayListCartModel.get(0).getItemCount())+" Items");

            PopupDelveryOptionsAdapter adapter=new PopupDelveryOptionsAdapter(mContext,arrayListCartModel);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            customDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

[Screenshot for a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu6Jo.png)

Does Anyone have the answer

Comment: show your java code.

Comment: Ok i have edited the question please check

Comment: have you tried using alertdialog.builder and listview is old u could ve used Recyclerview

Comment: `customDialog .getWindow().setLayout(SETWIDTH,SETHEIGHT);`

Comment: My answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47049149/3395198

Comment: How can i set SETWIDTH,SETHEIGHT

Comment: k will check it

Comment: I have used recyclerView but i think this layout just needs listview thats why i used LIstView

Answer (score 0):

Try using AlertBuilder

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, style_to_be_use));

        view = inflater.inflate(your_layoutID,null);
        alertDialog.setView(view);
        alertDialog.setTitle("your title");

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                  //function body
           });
 alertDialog.create();
 alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Hii what is parameter style_to_be_use.

Comment: <style name="myDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        ...
    </style>

Comment: this is what i have used u can use this copy paste in your style directory.

Comment: and change style_to_be_use to  R.style.myDialog

Answer (score 0):

> Replace  your TextView with this

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/popup_dismiss_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/layout_popup"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:text="DISMISS"
android:textColor="@color/orange"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but i have a doubt if the listview have lot of items then the dismiss text will go to the bottom of the listview right.. I need the dismiss text fixed on layout bottom

Comment: yes u are right so use Frame layout and adjust your list view and textview

Comment: if you found my answer helpful +1 would be appreciated.

Comment: I have solved it using weightsum properties i dont think thats a proper way but now its working fine atleast

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear Layout as a parent layout instead of RelativeLayout

Comment: but i need the dismiss button fixed on bottom.. How can i do that with LinearLayout

Comment: Show me image of your dialog  i will give you perfect answer

Comment: @SahdevRajput74I  have shared Image n the Question

Comment: use LinearLayout  height="wrap_content" and put your dissmiss Button after ListView. if you want to FIXED bottom side Dissmiss button then Dialog will display full screen