# Android CustomDialog minWidth

Tags: android, dialog

I have a CustomDialog (extending Dialog) which is currently set to wrap_content for both width and heigh. Problem is if I set the main text as something really short (say "hello") the dialog gets very small in width. I would like the dialog to always take all the space available, but still have the default margin from the edges of the screen.

I already tried various methods:

setting:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

on the dialog layout, doesn't have any effect.

doing:

```
int width = (int)(getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.90);
getWindow().setLayout(width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

causes the dialog to go at the start of the screen and doesn't change anything regarding the width

```
Window window = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
        params.horizontalMargin = 10;
        params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        window.setAttributes(params);
```

makes the dialog take the whole screen but without any horizonthal margin

putting

```
<item name="windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
        <item name="windowMinWidthMinor">65%</item>
```

in the dialog style has no effect.

how do I accomplish that? Mind that the dialog is used all around the app, so putting any code outside of the dialog class itself is not an option.

Comment: `android:minHeight=""
              android:minWidth=""` did you try this

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28714522/5110595)

Comment: @hemantParmar setting minimum width works but it involves using a fixed dimension. the other solution doesn't work for me

Comment: ok so you want dynamic min width?

Comment: yes, if possible I would like to just have the standard dialog margin

Comment: just check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7655350/5110595)