# Android: Dialog box is too narrow

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

So whenever I click a button in order to show my dialog box, it displays the dialog box like this, its too narrow.[Sorry new account image of **un-intended** results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWGU2.png).please help me fix this, I want it to show like in the designer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39kwT.png) ( again sorry for external links).

Here is the xml code for the dialog fragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    tools:text="Enter new member details"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/instructions_text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/name_layout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/instructions_text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/surname_layout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:hint="@string/surname"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surname"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/dob_layout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:hint="@string/birth_date"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/surname_layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/date_of_birth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/add"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dob_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dob_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I found a somewhat similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133822/custom-dialog-too-small) from 8 years ago, a "solution was to set min-width and min-height , but I don't want to hard-code values in for such kind of an issue, I did try that and it worked but it looked weird on another device I tested. Isn't there a more official or better solution to that? Thanks for any input. Oh also here is my code for the dialog box inflator:

```
class NewMemberDialogue: DialogFragment() {
private lateinit var binding: DialogLayoutBinding
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = DialogLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
    binding.cancelButton.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
    return binding.root
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

"Dialogs are sized by their content. You can add padding and margins on the outer layout to consume more space, but that will not redistribute the views inside."

[Custom dialog too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133822/custom-dialog-too-small)