# Android custom alert dialog with rounded corners and transparent background

Tags: android, transparency, android-alertdialog, rounded-corners

I have created a custom AlertDialog with rounded corners using `onDraw` of `LinearLayout` as below,

```
public class RoundedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

private Paint drawPaint;
private Paint roundPaint;

private int mCornerRadius = 100;

private RectF bounds;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public RoundedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    onInit();
}

public RoundedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    onInit();
}

public RoundedLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    onInit();
}

protected void onInit() {
    drawPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    drawPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
    drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

    roundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    roundPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);

    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if (w != oldw && h != oldh) {
        bounds = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
    }
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) bounds.width(), (int) bounds.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    super.dispatchDraw(c);

    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    canvas.drawRoundRect(bounds, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, paint);
}
}
```

And then I added transparency by `getWindow()` and setting `window.alpha = 0.5f` .
The resulting dialog is,

[image: Custom alert with transparency]

I want to remove those corner white background. I have searched 100s of questions here and no answer could get me the perfect rounded corner alert dialog. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Dialog - Rounded Corners and Transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861310/android-dialog-rounded-corners-and-transparency)

Answer (score 9):

I use this and it worked for me:

```
ConfirmacionMensaje customDialog = new ConfirmacionMensaje(MainActivity.this);
customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
customDialog.show();
```

ConfirmacionMensaje exntends from Dialog

and this is my xml for Dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<solid android:color="#ffDB0000"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: how to do it for popup? I tried this popup.getContentView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent); but didn't work

Answer (score 6):

Do use alert dialog use simple dialog

```
 LayoutInflater  factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        Dialog  dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

            dialog.setContentView(your layout);

            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: According to [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html): "The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly."This might resolve the transparent corner issue, but for me it introduced other problems.

Comment: I tried over a dozen different things, and this is indeed the only one that worked. You have to use a simple `Dialog`, regardless of what the docs say.

Answer (score 6):

Use this :

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

It is the simplest solution and it works.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_verification));
```

background verification is my drawable file

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved:

```
   dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_verification));
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you want to use a dialog?
it seems more like a temporary popup, like a toast or a crouton:

- http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/
- http://www.androidviews.net/2013/05/httpsimonvt-github-iomessagebar/
- https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/RA9WEEGWYp6 .

about the background, you could use one with 9-patch or a custom xml drawable (example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16161493/878126) and [**here**](http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-layout-rounded-corner-border/)) ...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LeeTaylor It's a lot of code to copy to here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If your dialog is an instance of either `AlertDialog` or `Dialog` add the following to your codes:

```
myDialog
    .getWindow()
    .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(0,0,0,0)));
```

Side note: Extending `LinearLayout` for applying rounded box, in my opinion is not a good practice, You can alternatively do this by the very straightforward XML representation, in this case a XML rectangular shape can help much more :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <corners
        android:radius="3dp" />
    ...
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! I tried both already but could not get that white corners away.

Answer (score 1):

this is worked for me,for the first time

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_verification));
```

here i am getting the resource from drawable  folder,background_verification is drawable file

Answer (score 0):

1. create xml in drawable folder with dialog_corner.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="@color/main_background"/>
   <corners
       android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/margin_10" android:topRightRadius="@dimen/margin_10"
       android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/margin_10" android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/margin_10" />
   </shape>`

2.put in layout

android:background="@drawable/dialog_corner"

3.in you java file keep below code

```
View mView =LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_pob,null); 
         alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new   ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```